# AngularJS - Sorting ng-repeat on string with numbers in them

Tags: javascript, string, angularjs, sorting, numbers

I have a list of objects in a table-view i would like to sort properly.

Amongst other things, my objects contain a name-field. This name field can also contain numbers, so for example:

`Chairman
Seat 1
Seat 2
Seat 3
Seat 11
Seat 12
Seat 23
Secretary`

This is however sorted like this:

`Chairman
Seat 1
Seat 11
Seat 12
Seat 2
Seat 23
Seat 3
Secretary`

This doesn't seem like a natural way of sorting my list when sorting by name.

Now i'm using the ng-repeat like this:

`seat in seats | orderBy:orderField:orderReverse track by seat.id`

Where `orderfield` is some variable that is set when clicking the table header and `orderReverse` is too for reversing.

I've tried making a custom filter to makes sure it behaves properly but i failed. It seems that Javascript just won't order it normally unless i break up the string. But i'd rather not because the data is often updated by polling. Another way would be to force leading zero's but since users are entering this stuff manually i'm not sure if i should.

Also, its not only names with numbers in them, so i can't just completely cut them off

So, any suggestions on how to make this list show normally?

Edit: cleared up some info about the problem.

Comment: You should write your own sorting function.

Comment: Search for "natural sort".

Comment: @dfsq i could do that but how would i know the difference between with number and without. And how would i give them the proper order?

Comment: @blackhole, i've tried that before submitting but that doesn't really seem to work if you want to sort by multiple columns correctly. I'll investigate further and post a jsfiddle if i can't work it out.

Comment: And why did my question get -1? It had enough info to create an answer didn't it?

Comment: Tweaks are not needed anymore, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46098059/4578952)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do Natural sorting in angularJs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231879/how-to-do-natural-sorting-in-angularjs)

Comment: Such tweaks are not needed anymore. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46098059/4578952)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a custom sort function with `orderBy` (it can take custom sorting function too)

define a sort function in your controller:

```
$scope.sorter = function (a){
   return parseInt(a.replace( /^\D+/g, '')); // gets number from a string
}
```

and then in your template

```
seat in seats | orderBy:sorter track by seat.id
```

**Edit** as per the modified problem statement:

Do manual sorting in controller instead of with ng-repeart using [naturalSort](http://www.overset.com/2008/09/01/javascript-natural-sort-algorithm/)

```
$scope.seats = [{"id": "Seat 12"},{"id": "Seat 3"},{"id": "Seat 1"},{"id": "Seat 2"},{"id": "Secretary"}];
$scope.seats.sort(function(a,b) {
    return naturalSort(a.id, b.id);
})
```

or check this angular module http://blog.overzealous.com/post/55829457993/natural-sorting-within-angular-js and the fiddle demonstrating it - http://jsfiddle.net/wE7H2/3/

Comment: I've cleared it up a bit: it also contains normal strings, so i need to keep them around too.

Comment: Then I will point you to http://www.overset.com/2008/09/01/javascript-natural-sort-algorithm/

and suggest you to do manual sorting in `controller` instead of with `ng-repeart`

Comment: Updated the answer! You can remove the old answer if the later works for you!

Comment: I've found this http://blog.overzealous.com/post/55829457993/natural-sorting-within-angular-js. Probably this should work for you!! Jsfiddle demostrating it - http://jsfiddle.net/wE7H2/3/

Comment: I've tried your solution and ended up with a slight adjustment. Mainly because i have multiple columns to filter by and refresh my code with promises. I also didn't use this naturalsort library but a similar one found here: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2495-user-friendly-sort-of-alpha-numeric-data-in-javascript.htm . But thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Finally a solution that does not simply use a filter on ng-repeat. If you are using pagination your method is the only one that works. Thanks so much!

Comment: Just tried the overzealous.com Angular plug-in you linked. Works great! Super easy to plug in and use.Common problem, great solution.

Comment: As of Angular 1.5.7, such tweaks are not needed anymore. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46098059/4578952)