# How to do Natural sorting in angularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object like this below:

```
scope.obj=[{option :"option 1"
},{option :"option 2"
},{option :"option 3"
},{option :"option k"
}]
```

and my html

```
<a ng-repeat="item in obj | orderBy :'option':false">{{item.option}}</a>
```

and expecting to display the object list in ascending order like below:

```
option k
option 1
option 2
option 3
```

but getting output as

```
option 1
option 2
option 3
option k
```

I have tried with many solution given in stackoverflow and other sites but nothing is working.
Pls help me to solve this issue

My expectation is if any character after "option" string (like option k,option L etc) there should come first in ascending order then number should come(option k,option L,option 1,option 2,etc)

Comment: You are getting what you should, numbers when ordered along with words come first. OS often sort directory the same way with numbers and special characters at the top of alpha named ones.

Comment: ok What can i do to get the result as i expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by spliting the string into 2 parts by Space,converting the 2nd part to integer ,if it is "k" giving -1 as value and then sorting array by converted 2nd part of the string.code is given below

```
for ( var i = 0; i < scope.obj.length; i++) {
                var option= scope.obj[i].option.split(" ");
                scope.obj[i].optionValue = parseInt(optionValueSet(option[1]));
            }

function optionValueSet(value) {
            if (value=== "K"){
                return -1;
            } 
            return value;
        }
```

and my html

```
<a ng-repeat="item in obj | orderBy :'optionValue':false">{{item.option}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) says it only sorts numbers (using the natural order) or strings (alphabetically, where numbers are always smaller than letters), so I think you should [sort the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) before the ng-repeat:

```
myArray.sort(function myCustomSortFunction(a,b) {...})
```

Answer (score 0):

As of AngularJS 1.5.7, a `comparator` argument can be passed as a 4th argument to the `orderBy` filter. You can then tweak the comparison between elements.

*controller.js*

```
$scope.naturalCompare = function(a, b) {
  return naturalSort(a.value, b.value);
}
```

*view.html*

```
<span ng-repeat="item in list | orderBy: 'name' : false : naturalCompare">item.name</span>
```

---

In here we implented a shortcut in a module [angularjs-naturalorderby](https://github.com/Citymagine/angularjs-naturalorderby) which uses [javascript-natural-sort](https://github.com/overset/javascript-natural-sort). So you can use it like.

*view.html*

```
<span ng-repeat="item in list | naturalOrderBy: 'name'">item.name</span>
```