# Natural search the object array with numbers and text in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, natural-sort

I have array as following, I need it to apply natural sort on this, on only **text** field.

```
    var data = [{
        "text": "1001",
        "value": "212121"
    }, {
        "text": "1002",
        "value": "32435"
    }, {
        "text": "A101",
        "value": "324124324"
    }, {
        "text": "A12",
        "value": "567y54645"
    }, {
        "text": "A123",
        "value": "534534"
    }, {
        "text": "A21",
        "value": "34534534"
    }, {
        "text": "A210",
        "value": "5345345"
    }, {
        "text": "A33",
        "value": "234234234"
    }, 
        "text": "B2",
        "value": "4234234"
    }, {
        "text": "D10000",
        "value": "34234234"
    }, {
        "text": "EZH43NUT8SD",
        "value": "534534534"
    }, {
        "text": "H287",
        "value": "43435345"
    }, {
        "text": "Pkg test",
        "value": "5345345"
    }]
```

I have tried following things so far :

http://jsfiddle.net/wE7H2/3/

[AngularJS - Sorting ng-repeat on string with numbers in them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766876/angularjs-sorting-ng-repeat-on-string-with-numbers-in-them)

Comment: What do you mean by `natural sort ` in this context?

Comment: Do you mean lexicographical sort ?

Comment: _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)."_

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have marked correct answer I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) with `options`

> **sensitivity**
>
> Which differences in the strings should lead to non-zero result values. Possible values are:
>
> - `"base"`: Only strings that differ in base letters compare as unequal. Examples: `a ≠ b`, `a = á`, `a = A`.
> - `"accent"`: Only strings that differ in base letters or accents and other diacritic marks compare as unequal. Examples: `a ≠ b`, `a ≠ á`, `a = A`.
> - `"case"`: Only strings that differ in base letters or case compare as unequal. Examples: `a ≠ b`, `a = á`, `a ≠ A`.
> - `"variant"`: Strings that differ in base letters, accents and other diacritic marks, or case compare as unequal. Other differences may also be taken into consideration. Examples: `a ≠ b`, `a ≠ á`, `a ≠ A`.
>
> The default is "variant" for usage "sort"; it's locale dependent for usage "search".
>
> **numeric**
>
> Whether numeric collation should be used, such that "1" < "2" < "10". Possible values are `true` and `false`; the default is `false`. This option can be set through an options property or through a Unicode extension key; if both are provided, the `options` property takes precedence. Implementations are not required to support this property.

```js
var data = [{ text: "1001", value: "212121" }, { text: "1002", value: "32435" }, { text: "A101", value: "324124324" }, { text: "A12", value: "567y54645" }, { text: "A123", value: "534534" }, { text: "A21", value: "34534534" }, { text: "A210", value: "5345345" }, { text: "A33", value: "234234234" }, { text: "B2", value: "4234234" }, { text: "D10000", value: "34234234" }, { text: "EZH43NUT8SD", value: "534534534" }, { text: "H287", value: "43435345" }, { text: "Pkg test", value: "5345345" }, { text: "RRG46AXC3PO", value: "3434354" }, { text: "yoyo", value: "534534534" }];

data.sort(function (a,b) {
    return a.text.localeCompare(b.text, undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' });
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, Thank you so much. :)